# Next Page not opening using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

Below is the HTML I'm working with. I'm trying to click Next using python + Selenium, but I'm getting an error.

```
<li class="item pages-item-next">
  <a class="action  next" href="https://oup.com.pk/academic-generalbooks.html?p=2" title="Next">
    <span class="label">Page</span>
    <span>Next</span>
  </a>
</li>
```

My code:

```
x = browser.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,'action.next')
x.click()
```

Why am I getting this exception?

```
ElementNotInteractableException
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Root cause:**

`By.CLASS_NAME,'action.next'` - This is incorrect.

`By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.action.next'` This is correct

Try this using XPATH locator:

```
x = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[contains(@class,'action  next')]")))
x.click()
```

Imports:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
```

Answer (score 1):

I know you already accepted an answer but it doesn't explain WHY you received the error. The problem is with your locator

```
(By.CLASS_NAME,'action.next')
```

`By.CLASS_NAME` expects a single class name but "action" and "next" are both classes (and you've added a `.` between them that makes it look like a CSS selector). So, both of the locators below would be valid

```
(By.CLASS_NAME,'action')
(By.CLASS_NAME,'next')
```

but my guess is that you will need both classes to uniquely identify the element so you should use a CSS selector

```
(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'.action.next')
```

In CSS selector syntax, you add a `.` before each class name.